# Show that $(1-\beta)(p+\beta)=1$

Tags: radicals, binomial-theorem

> If $$(7+4\sqrt{3})^n = p+\beta,$$ where $n$ and $p$ are positive integers and $\beta$ is a proper fraction, then show that $$(1-\beta)(p+\beta)=1.$$

I cant even understand how to express the term in a positive number and a proper fraction. I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: By "proper fraction", do we mean a real number between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Yeah, the proper fraction means that

Comment: Hint: $(7+4\sqrt{3})(7-4\sqrt{3}) = 1$.

Comment: No its $1-beta$

Comment: @dxiv No, it is $1 - \beta$.

Comment: @6005 Sorry, misread what "*proper fraction*" meant. I fixed my comment above.

Comment: This question needs to be dealt with something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun question! The key realization is that
$$
(7 + 4\sqrt{3})^n + (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
(do you see why?) and moreover, that
$$
0 < (7 - 4\sqrt{3}) < 1,
$$
so that
$$
0 < (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^n < 1,
$$
for all natural numbers $n$.
It follows from here that
\begin{align*}
p &= (7 + 4\sqrt{3})^n + (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^n - 1 \\
\beta &= 1 - (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^n.
\end{align*}
Now to finish, we see directly from the above that
\begin{align*}
p + \beta &= (7 + 4\sqrt{3})^n \\
1 - \beta &= (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^n.
\end{align*}
Multiply them together and see what you get.

Comment: I didnt get how did we get values of p and beta

Comment: I took p as (7+4√3)^n + (7-4√3)^n and beta as (7-4√3)^n which becomes (7+4√3)^n when we add them. But when i solve it, i dont get the answer

Comment: Oh , i get it we actually added 1 in the p term and subtracted 1 from the beta term, their meanings remain the same still

Comment: @user354545 Yes. You should check that the $\beta$ I gave is between $0$ and $1$, and that $p + \beta$ is $(7 + 4\sqrt{3})^n$. That alone means that we picked the right $p$ and $\beta$

Comment: Yeah but beta = 1-(7+4√3)^n acheives the value 1 when n is a higher power

Comment: @user354545 It gets very close to $1$, but never achieves it.

Comment: I plugged the values in calculator and it says 1 when n is very high. Must be approximated value then

Comment: @user354545 Yes, calculators have a bit of error :) You put in too high of an $n$ and it rounds to $1$, but it's not $1$, just very close.

Comment: Yeah man, thanks so much

Comment: @user354545 You're welcome. Thanks for the question!